# Change font colour of picker on iOS in Titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

How can I change the text colour of a [picker](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker) using Titanium on the iOS platform.

From the looks of it, I can only change the background colour, and I can only change the font colour on the Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a PickerRow, you can set the color property:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.PickerRow-property-color

If that doesn't work, then you can do same as the example which is in the link above (creating Labels and adding them to each PickerRow):

```
var fruit = [ 'Bananas', 'Strawberries', 'Mangos', 'Grapes' ];

var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

for(var i=0, ilen=fruit.length; i<ilen; i++){
  var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow();

  var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color:'red',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontWeight:'bold'},
    text: fruit[i],
    textAlign:'left',
    width:'126'
  });

  row.add(label);
  column1.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Setting a colour on the PickerRow itself worked. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at themes attributes like below:

```
<style name="PickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>


<!-- Use this style for Spinners/Plain Pickers in default state -->
<style name="SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>


<!-- Use this style for Spinners/Plain Pickers in selected/popup state -->
<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:background">#20767a</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's for Android. I need help with iOS

Comment: Then below answer should work for Ti SDK 5.4.0 or above.